# Need help adding Supervisor on this template

Tags: templates

Im fairly new to latex, and i wanted do add to this template a supervisor, just like advisor and coadvisor. I've tried modifying the coadvisor parts, but it didnt work. Its a portuguese template (Brazil), but written in english.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4n7bidwy966qox/mdtufsm.cls?dl=0

Here is the program

```
    %\listfiles
\documentclass[tg]{mdtufsm}
% um tipo específico de monografia pode ser informado como parâmetro opcional:
%\documentclass[tese]{mdtufsm}
% a opção `openright' pode ser usada para forçar inícios de capítulos
% em páginas ímpares
%\documentclass[openright]{mdtufsm}
% para gerar uma versão frente-e-verso, use a opção 'twoside':
% \documentclass[twoside]{mdtufsm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % pacote para conj. de caracteres correto
\usepackage{fix-cm} %para funcionar corretamente o tamanho das fontes da capa
\usepackage{times, color, xcolor}       % pacote para usar fonte Adobe Times e cores
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % pacote para acentuação
\usepackage{graphicx}  % pacote para importar figuras
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsfonts} %Pacotes matemáticos
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[%hidelinks%,
            bookmarksopen=true,linktoc=none,colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue,
            pdftitle={Título da Dissertação ou Trabalho ....},
            pdfauthor={Nome Autor Sobrenome},
            pdfsubject={Dissertação de Mestrado},
            pdfkeywords={Dissertação, Modelo, LaTeX}
            ]{hyperref} %hidelinks disponível no pacote hyperref a partir da versão 2011-02-05  6.82a
%Nesse caso, hidelinks retira os retângulos em volta dos links das referências

%Margens conforme MDT 7ª edição, arrumar diretamente no mdtufsm.cls para funcionar a opção twoside *PENDENTE*
\usepackage[inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

%==============================================================================
% Se o pacote hyperref foi carregado a linha abaixo corrige um bug na hora
% de montar o sumário da lista de figuras e tabelas
% Se o pacote não foi carregado, comentar a linha %
%==============================================================================
\input{macros/bugcaption}

%==============================================================================
% Identificação do trabalho
%==============================================================================
\title{title}

\author{Scalcon}{Filipe}
%Descomentar se for uma "autora"
%\autoratrue

\course{Engenharia Elétrica}
\altcourse{Curso de Engenharia Elétrica}

\institute{Centro de Tecnologia}
\degree{Bacharel em Engenharia Elétrica}

% Número do TG (verificar na secretaria do curso)
% Para mestrado deixar sem opção dentro do {}
\trabalhoNumero{}

%Orientador
\advisor[Prof.]{Dr.}{Vieira}{Rodrigo Padilha}
%Se for uma ``orientadora'' descomentar a linha baixo
%\orientadoratrue

%Co orientador, comentar se não existir
%\coadvisor[Prof.]{Drª.}{Pereira}{Maria Regina}
%\coorientadoratrue %Se for uma ``Co-Orientadora''

%Avaliadores (Banca)
\committee[Me.]{Gabbi}{Thieli Smidt}{UFSM}
\committee[]{Osório}{Caio Ruviaro Dantas}{UFSM}

% a data deve ser a da defesa; se nao especificada, são gerados
% mes e ano correntes
\date{16}{Dezembro}{2016}

%Palavras chave
\keyword{}
\keyword{}
\keyword{}
\keyword{}


%%=============================================================================
%% Início do documento
%%=============================================================================
\begin{document}

%%=============================================================================
%% Capa e folha de rosto
%%=============================================================================
\maketitle

%%=============================================================================
%% Catalogação (obrigatório para mestrado) e Folha de aprovação
%%=============================================================================
%Somente obrigatório para dissertação, para TG, remover as linhas   77  %
%Como a CIP vai ser impressa atrás da página de rosto, as margens inner e outer 
%devem ser invertidas.
\newgeometry{inner=20mm,outer=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm}    
\makeCIP{filipescalcon1@gmail.com} %email do autor      
\restoregeometry

%Se for usar a catalogação gerada pelo gerador do site da biblioteca comentar as linhas
%acima e utilizar o comando abaixo
%\includeCIP{CIP.pdf}

%folha de aprovação
\makeapprove
```

There's more parts, but the errors i get are at the make aprove, maybe related to the changes to the class file.

Comment: You can add a minimal working program, showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you look at the dropbox file, you'll see the part where it defines advisor and coadvisor. I basically copied them and replaced with supervisor, unfortunatelly it didn't work. This is the original template, i didnt save the previous one i changed, i can do it again if you need it

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please post the document that didn't work, by [editing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/340323/edit) your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the file, for example before
`\DeclareRobustCommand{\advisor}`

```
\newif\ifsupervisora
\DeclareRobustCommand{\supervisor}[4][]{
        \gdef\@supervisorlast{#3}
        \gdef\@supervisorfirst{#4}
        \gdef\@supervisor{#1~#2~#4 #3}
        \gdef\@supervisorcommittee{#4 #3, #2}
        \gdef\@supervisorwithouttitle{#4 #3}
}
```

Then where it says:

```
\@ifundefined{@advisor}{}{
  \vfill{\LargeC\textbf{\iforientadora\advisornamef\else\advisorname\fi:~\@advisor}}}
\@ifundefined{@coadvisor}{}{
  \\[6ex]{\LargeC\textbf{\ifcoorientadora\coadvisornamef\else\coadvisorname\fi:~\@coadvisor}}}
```

add

```
\@ifundefined{@supervisor}{}{
  \\[6ex]{\LargeC\textbf{\ifsupervisora\supervisornamef\else\supervisorname\fi:~\@supervisor}}}
```

either before or after, depending on where you want it on the title page

And in brazilian.babel and english.babel add definitions for `\advisorname` and `\advisornamef`.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunatelly i get some errors just for edditing the babel. The main one complaining for not having a \begin{document}. Just to make things clear, i've used this to write my final work for college, and i wanted to use latex for my internship report, the same file and structure, unfortunatelly i cant add the "supervisor" bit.

Comment: The "coadvisor" part works fine, i tried just changing its portuguese translation to supervisor which would have been enough) and it did not compile the file.

Comment: There are actually three places involved: (1) the definition of the command, like `\supervisor` or \`coadvisor`. This fills a couple of macros with information; (2) the place where this information is used in the title page; (3) the translation of the term "supervisor" in Brazilian or English in the files brazilian.babel and english.babel. See my answer. I tried it with some dissertation file the I found on the internet and it works.

Comment: It worked fine now, i was editing it on notepad, that was my bad. I answered it yesterday but it got deleted. Thank you very much.